# Using Async IO for processing observables when using Reactive Extensions (Rx)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

How can I use async IO (e.g. WriteAsyn, SaveAsync) when processing messages from an observable stream?

I am currently using Rx to stream messages read from client socket as an observable. A simplified version, using extension methods, would be:

```
var messagesFromClient = socket.ReadChunksAsObservable()
    .ScanChunksIntoFrames()
    .MapFrameToString()
    .DoLogString()
    .FilterEmptyStrings()
    .MapToMessageObject();
```

Now, I am struggling on how to save this messages in my repository, since my repository has only TPL async non blocking methods that underline use async IO (e.g. `await dbConnection.SaveAsync(...)`)

From what I have read and tested, it is not possible to just do something like:

```
messagesFromClient.Subscribe(async message=>{
    await myRepo.SaveAsync();
});
```

Where can I use those async IO operations? Should I handle those as side effects? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Observable` from an `async` method using `Observable.FromAsync`, then flatmap `messagesFromClient` to this observable:

```
messagesFromClient
    .SelectMany(message => Observable.FromAsync(() => myRepo.SaveAsync(message)))
    .Subscribe();
```

Comment: It makes sense. But that SelectMany would not make my messages being processed concurrently? Maybe a Merge() would do it! Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: @FilipeBorges: `SelectMany` project each element into an observable (in this case by invoking the async function) and `merge` these observables, so messages are processed concurrently (If `SaveAsync` actually introduces concurrency).